# How to declare a global variable-sized and variable-valued one-dimensional array of localparam in Verilog/SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to declare an array of parameters called WEIGHT inside a module. However, the size of the array as well as its values depend on a parameter for the module called NFFT. Here is a code snippet of what I want to do exactly:

```
module mymod#(parameter NFFT = 16)(
...
);

genvar i;

generate
  if(NFFT == 16)
    localparam [$clog2(NFFT) : 0] WEIGHT [0 : $clog2(NFFT)-2] = '{4, 16, 4};
  else if(NFFT == 32)
    localparam [$clog2(NFFT) : 0] WEIGHT [0 : $clog2(NFFT)-2] = '{4, 8, 32, 4};
endgenerate 

generate
  for(i = 1; i <= $clog2(NFFT); i = i + 1) begin
    ...
    anothermod #(
      .STAGE_WEIGHT ( WEIGHTS[i] )
      ) U0_anothermod(
      ...
      )
  end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

However, the problem with this code is that, this way, the scope of WEIGHT becomes local to the first generate block only. So, when used in the second generate block, the simulator gives an error that WEIGHT is an undefined variable. Is there a work around for this problem? I am open to any suggestions whether in Verilog or SystemVerilog.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work around for this problem. A code snippet is provided below with the solution:

```
module mymod#(parameter NFFT = 16)(
...
);

genvar i;

localparam [$clog2(NFFT)-1:0] WEIGHT [0 : $clog2(NFFT)-2] = (NFFT == 8) ? '{1, 2} :
                                                            (NFFT == 16) ? '{3, 4, 5} : '{6, 7, 8, 9};

generate
    for(i = 1; i <= $clog2(NFFT); i = i + 1) begin
        ...
        anothermod #(.STAGE_WEIGHT ( WEIGHTS[i] )) U0_anothermod(
            ...
        )
    end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a localparam is limited to the block in which it is declared. In your case, the localparam **WEIGHT** is declared inside a generate block, so it's scope is limited to that block. When you try to use it in the second generate block, the simulator gives an error because **WEIGHT** is not defined in that scope.

You can declare **WEIGHT** as a parameter of the module, and then use a generate block to assign values to it based on the value of **NFFT**.

Example;

```
module mymod#(parameter NFFT = 16, parameter [$clog2(NFFT)-1:0] WEIGHT [0 : $clog2(NFFT)-2])(
...
);

genvar i;

generate
 if(NFFT == 16)
   WEIGHT = '{4, 16, 4};
 else if(NFFT == 32)
   WEIGHT = '{4, 8, 32, 4};
endgenerate 

generate
 for(i = 1; i <= $clog2(NFFT); i = i + 1) begin
   ...
   anothermod #(
     .STAGE_WEIGHT ( WEIGHT[i] )
     ) U0_anothermod(
     ...
     )
 end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

Above code, **WEIGHT** is declared as a parameter of the module, so it is accessible in all blocks within the module. The generate block assigns values to **WEIGHT** based on the value of **NFFT**. Then, in the second generate block, you can use **WEIGHT** just like a regular array.

*This assumes that the size of **WEIGHT** is the same for all values of **NFFT**. If the size of **WEIGHT** can vary depending on **NFFT**, you might need to use a more complex approach, such as dynamic arrays or associative arrays, which are available in SystemVerilog but not in plain Verilog.

Comment: Thank you Keyboard Corporation for your reply. Unfortunately, your suggestion does not work because when you define a parameter for a module, you can only override its default value either when instantiating this module using parameter override (#) or using defparam statement. Accordingly, the code you have suggested gives an error because it is not allowed to change the value of a module's parameter inside the module itself.

Anyways, I have found a work around and posted it as an answer. Again, thanks a lot Keyboard Corporation for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access identifiers (in this case the `parameter WEIGHT`) declared inside an unnamed generate block from outside its scope. Give the block a name and you can access

```
module mymod#(parameter NFFT = 32)();

  if(NFFT == 16) begin : N
    localparam [$clog2(NFFT) : 0] WEIGHT [0 : $clog2(NFFT)-2] = '{4, 16, 4};
  end
  else if(NFFT == 32) begin : N
    localparam [$clog2(NFFT) : 0] WEIGHT [0 : $clog2(NFFT)-2] = '{4, 8, 32, 4};
  end
 
  for(genvar i = 1; i <= $clog2(NFFT); i++) begin : mods
    anothermod #(
      .STAGE_WEIGHT ( N.WEIGHT[i] ) // note reference to N.
    ) U0_anothermod();
  end

endmodule 

module anothermod #(parameter int STAGE_WEIGHT);
  initial $display("%m %d", STAGE_WEIGHT);
endmodule
```

Note: you have a few errors in your index calculations, but that hould be easy for you to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another suggestion: you could use an intermediate parameterized module as in the following example.

```
module mymod#(parameter NFFT = 16)(
// ...
);

  if(NFFT == 16)
    mymod2#(NFFT, '{4, 16, 4}) mymod2();
  else if(NFFT == 32)
    mymod2#(NFFT, '{4, 16, 32, 4}) mymod2();

endmodule 

module mymod2#(parameter NFFT = 16, parameter int WEIGHTS[0:$clog2(NFFT)-2] = '{default: 1})(
// ...
);
  
  for(genvar i = 1; i < $clog2(NFFT); i = i + 1) begin
    anothermod #(
      .STAGE_WEIGHT ( WEIGHTS[i-1] )
      ) U0_anothermod(
      // ...
    );
  end
endmodule

module anothermod#(int STAGE_WEIGHT = 1)();
  initial begin
    $display("%m: %d", STAGE_WEIGHT);
  end
endmodule

module top();
  mymod #(16) m1();
  mymod #(32) m2();
endmodule
```

BTW, you had issues with indexing in the original post which I fixed in the example.

also, the following declaration looks a bit simpler and works with major simulators:

```
module mymod2#( int NFFT = 16,  int WEIGHTS[] = '{})(
// ...
);
```